# Composer update created error: require(vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento2, composer, composer-update

I have updated Composer to 2.4.4 as a prerequisite to updating Magento to 2.4.5, however now I'm getting errors in SSH when trying to run any other command and HTTP on a page execution:

SSH:

```
In AutoloadGenerator.php line 1351:
                                                                                                                                                                         
  require(/home/---/web/---/public_html/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

HTTP:

```
Warning: require(/home/---/web/---/public_html/vendor/composer/../magento/composer-root-update-plugin/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xadmin/web/xdev.devsetup.co.uk/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/---/web/---/public_html/vendor/composer/../magento/composer-root-update-plugin/registration.php' (include_path='/home/xadmin/web/xdev.devsetup.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /home/---/web/---/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59
```

Composer won't rollback - tried that and received the same errors. Confirmed the file doesn't exist, but the directory does.

I'm assuming `/public_html/vendor/composer/../magento/composer-root-update-plugin/` in the HTTP error is the same as `/public_html/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/` in SSH, but posted in case it helps you help me.

Does anyone know how I can get past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to upgrade to Magento 2.4.4 before upgrading to Magento 2.4.5. You can upgrade to Magento 2.4.5 directly.

**Solution 1:**
Try the following steps to upgrade your Magento site to 2.4.5-p1:

1. Switch back to your old PHP version, ie. PHP 7.4 or 7.3
2. Run the following commands:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update
composer update
```

3. Change to PHP version 8.1
4. Run the following commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

**Solution 2:** (This solution resolved the issue for @myshadowself)

Take the following steps:

1. Remove vendor directory and clear composer cache:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer clear-cache
```

2. Update require-dev section in your composer.json file same as the Magento codebase: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5-p1/composer.json#L108
3. Remove manually magento/composer-root-update-plugin from `require` in composer.json
4. Run thee following commands:

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

You're done.

Troubleshooting:

If you had the below error when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

> "Class "Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent" not
> found#0
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()"

Remove **generated** folder then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` again:

```
rm -rf generated
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I was hoping you'd drop by Tu Van, I've been watching your bug hunts for a while!
Currently on my way home, but I'll try this in the morning. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, hope that helps you resolve your issue. If you have any issues, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi
I get as far as `composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5-p1 --no-update` but receive new errors:

Posted below...

Comment: Deprecation Notice: preg_match(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($subject) of type string is deprecated in /home/--/web/--/public_html/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/Utils/PackageUtils.php:128

In RootPackageRetriever.php line 517:

Comment: [TypeError]                                                                                                                              
  Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Updater\RootPackageRetriever::getOriginalEdition(): Return value must be of type string, null returned

Comment: + an exception trace too big to post as a comment.

I'm now running PHP 8.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you run `composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update` before?

Comment: Which Magento version you are using before this upgrade?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140533/discussion-between-tu-van-and-myshadowself).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer install
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

or you can remove `composer.lock` and then ran above command.

Hopefully this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

After running composer update in solution 1 I get this:

- php-amqplib/php-amqplib v3.2.0 conflicts with php 7.4.0 - 7.4.1.

Our dev server has both php7.4 and php8.1 on it.
I have to specify php7.4 for any php bin/magento commands but what about the composer command?
Andy